# git-svn clone failure, perl.exe failed assertion

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

My work has an absolutely massive and ancient code base that is very quickly becoming untenable for merging multiple projects together.  I am attempting to pull the repository - WITH its entire history - into git to solve some of these problems.

However, git svn is causing many problems when attempting to specify commands to ensure the entire history is pulled.

The svn repository and the client machine doing the pulling are both Windows 7-based (the svn repository is on a Server 2008 machine, but same core really).

These are the commands I have tried so far:

```
git svn clone "https://path/to/svn/" "local/repository/"
```

Issue: This retrieves a functional repository, but only pulls roughly 1/4th of the history associated with the repository, due to some major upgrade roughly a year ago that nobody can give me too many details on.  I do not know why this break occurs.  Some of the branches that are part of the repository, confusingly, have no commits in common with the main line trunk.  This very seriously compromises the merging benefits git brings.

```
git svn clone -T "https://path/to/svn/trunk/" "https://path/to/svn/" "local/repository"
```

Issue: No branches argument, doesn't properly retrieve the branches.

```
git svn clone --b="https://path/to/svn/branches" -T "https://path/to/svn/trunk/" "https://path/to/svn/" "local/repository"
```

Issue: The following error:

```
 subversion/libsvn_subr/path.c:115: failed assertion `is_canonical(component, clen)`.
 0 [sig] perl.exe" 4432 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to perl.exe.stackdump
```

The stack trace is an incomprehensible collection of pointer locations that provides no useful information.  An example:

```
Frame       Function      Args
028F668     74F21194      (000000EC, 0000EA60, 00000000, 0028F6BC)
```

Comment: Also: I have attempted minor semantic fixes, such as not using/using quotation marks, using --branches instead of -b, using or not using the equal sign, using or not using a trialing slash at the end of the URLs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the same problem as [git svn dcommit fails because of assertion error "svn_fspath__is_canonical(child_fspath)" (cygwin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693255/git-svn-dcommit-fails-because-of-assertion-error-svn-fspath-is-canonicalchild)

The suggested solutions might not be that satisfying (downgrade…), though.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked to see if you are running out of memory?  The original clone is really RAM intensive.  If you are you can do the clone on another machine and then transfer it to the development machine for use.

Comment: The clone in the basic command with no command switches starts at a very high revision number corresponding to when this import happened and runs to current.  I am relatively confident this is not a hardware-bound issue.