# How can I tell Cygwin that a dependency was built from source?

Tags: git, cygwin

I'm using Git with Cygwin (I prefer Cygwin to Mingw, and I do not grok PoshGit).

Unfortunately, the version of Git available on Cygwin repository is kind of old (1.7.9-1). So I built git 1.8 from source (which btw was in fact not so hard as I thought it would be, but I digress).

The only problem is that the Cygwin setup does not become "aware" that Git is already installed. If I try to install some package that depends on Git (for instance, [Tig](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/)), the Cygwin setup will tell me that it needs to install Git.

Is there any way to fix that? Can I inform, somehow, that Git is already installed, and that the Cygwin setup should try to use that to resolve any dependency on the Git package?

Comment: Maybe you can trick Cygwin by modifying the `.lst.gz` files in `/etc/setup` (http://superuser.com/a/155180/141)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem. Instead of installing a package for git-completion, there is another way to do it. Download the git-completion.bash file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash, put it in /etc/bash_completion.d/ directory, rename the file to "git" and restart Cygwin. You get git completion (assuming you have bash-completion installed already) without any dependencies. The disadvantage is that you don't have auto update for this file, but the Cygwin version is more ancient anyway.